# Setting up Postgresql. Not matching major version and server version

Tags: postgresql, macos

while trying to use psql I get the following output from the console.

```
   psql (12.4, server 13.0)
   WARNING: psql major version 12, server major version 13.
            Some psql features might not work.
```

I've used the following command `psql postgres`
Does anyone know how I can make them to be matching versions ?

Comment: You need to run `psql` from your Postgres 13 installation. Or remove Postgres 12 entirely.

Comment: Can you give me some more hints regarding that :)

Comment: What OS and how did you install Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I managed to sort it out by uninstalling postgresql completely using `brew uninstall postgresql` and then repeating the process.

Comment: Did you create a new one by removing the data from the Postgresql 12 install?